# Syntax for a list of tuples in F#

Tags: f#

I have the following Json to deserialize:

```
{"data":[{"a":[[6902.5,1474],[6903,110],[6903.5,75],[6904,3520],[6904.5,1075],[6905,5296],[6905.5,71],
[6906,1030],[6907,100],[6908,130]],"timestamp":"2020-03-25T10:02:15.098Z","b":[[6902,297],[6901.5,35],
[6900,59],[6899.5,10],[6899,69046],[6898,138210],[6896.5,60],[6896,30],[6894.5,258],[6894,672]]}]}
```

when I create a type to deserialize to, I can't find how to declare a list of tuples:

```
{
    A : float List List      // this compiles
    B : (float, float) List  // this doesn't compile
}
```

the elements always come as a pair and are unnamed, no exception.

how can I declare a list of tuples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list of tuples would be declared like so:

```
B : (float * float) list
```